# Facebook Ads SDK - Unsupported Post Request

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I got some example scripts from Facebook App Management to use the Marketing API. When I run the script, I just get this error by curl:

```
'Unsupported post request. Object with ID \'105101623679981\' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation.
```

I already tried to deactivate the Sandbox Mode and go public, tried many different scripts in different languages and also other keys.

Any Ideas?

This is the Script:

```
<?php
//Add all those Uses and the autoloader

$access_token = '<my_very_long_accessToken';
$ad_account_id = '<my_account_id>'; //<-- This is the Object in the Error Code
$app_secret = '<my_app_secret>';
$page_id = '<my_page_id>';
$app_id = '<my_app_is>';

$api = Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);
$api->setLogger(new CurlLogger());

$fields = array(
);
$params = array(
  'objective' => 'PAGE_LIKES',
  'status' => 'PAUSED',
  'buying_type' => 'AUCTION',
  'name' => 'My Campaign',
);
$campaign = (new AdAccount($ad_account_id))->createCampaign(
  $fields,
  $params
);
$campaign_id = $campaign->id;
echo 'campaign_id: ' . $campaign_id . "\n\n";

$fields = array(
);
$params = array(
  'status' => 'PAUSED',
  'targeting' => array('geo_locations' => array('countries' => array('US'))),
  'daily_budget' => '1000',
  'billing_event' => 'IMPRESSIONS',
  'bid_amount' => '20',
  'campaign_id' => $campaign_id,
  'optimization_goal' => 'PAGE_LIKES',
  'promoted_object' => array('page_id' =>  $page_id),
  'name' => 'My AdSet',
);
//...
```

Comment: you need to add the script(s).

Comment: Added it for you

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. I got it. It has to be "act_"

So bad. The Script is really crappy. So many Errors. And it's created by facebook!